# robot_localization TF problem

Tags: navigation, ekf, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I'm using ROS Indigo with V-REP simulator and `robot_localization` to fuse odom and imu data. I start the  `ekf_localization_node`, it does not display an error message, but does not publish anything.
Already, the debug file shows "Could not transform measurement into odom. Ignoring..." and "Could not transform measurement into base_link. Ignoring...".
V-REP publishes TF tree: map->odom->base_link->sparton. I checked tf and it's being made correctly. What's wrong?
The launch file is:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="ekf_localization_node" name="ekf_localization" clear_params="true">
  <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
  <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
  
  <param name="map_frame" value="/map"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="/odom"/>
  <param name="base_link_frame" value="/base_link"/>
  <param name="world_frame" value="/odom"/>
  
  <param name="transform_time_offset" value="0.0"/>

  <param name="odom0" value="/air2/odom"/>
  <param name="imu0" value="/air2/imu"/>

  <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true,  true,  true,
                                  true,  true,  true,
                                  false, false, false,
                                  true,  true,  true,
                                  false, false, false]</rosparam>

  <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                 true,  true,  true,
                                 false, false, false,
                                 true,  true,  true,
                                 true,  true,  true]</rosparam>

  <param name="odom0_differential" value="true"/>
  <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>

  <param name="odom0_relative" value="false"/>
  <param name="imu0_relative" value="false"/> 

  <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

  <param name="print_diagnostics" value="true"/>

  <param name="odom0_queue_size" value="10"/>
  <param name="imu0_queue_size" value="10"/>

  <param name="debug"           value="true"/>
  <param name="debug_out_file"  value="/home/robo/debug_ekf_localization.txt"/>
</node>
```

Odom topic:

```
header: 
  seq: 98
  stamp: 
    secs: 1443031642
    nsecs: 362367329
  frame_id: /odom
child_frame_id: /base_link
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -0.00514762103558
      y: 0.00168874696828
      z: 0.0593957901001
    orientation: 
      x: -0.707533717155
      y: 0.0267585106194
      z: 0.0170629229397
      w: -0.70596665144
  covariance: [0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: -0.0889131724834
      y: 0.0042970222421
      z: -2.02671504021
    angular: 
      x: -0.321618080139
      y: 4.16820764542
      z: -3.00630068779
  covariance: [0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0010000000474974513]
```

IMU topic:

```
header: 
  seq: 80
  stamp: 
    secs: 1443102518
    nsecs: 982325656
  frame_id: /sparton
orientation: 
  x: 0.476446002722
  y: 0.473839610815
  z: 0.526966273785
  w: -0.520367085934
orientation_covariance: [9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.000786931079347
  y: -0.00079421402188
  z: 0.00557178910822
angular_velocity_covariance: [9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.157026425004
  y: 0.0447424426675
  z: -9.79022026062
linear_acceleration_covariance: [9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.999999974752427e-07]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218197/robot_localization-tf-problem/) by [higorbarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23997/higorbarb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two things.

1.

> V-REP publishes TF tree:
> map->odom->base_link->sparton. I
> checked tf and it's being made
> correctly.

It is `ekf_localization_node`'s job to publish the *odom*->*base_link* transform or the *map*->*odom* transform (depending on what you have `world_frame` set to). If some other node is publishing them, that's a problem.

2. Get rid of the forward slashes in the `frame_id` fields of your input messages. `ekf_localization_node` uses `tf2`, and so it automatically strips leading forward slashes from your `*_frame` parameters in the launch file. See [this](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Migration#Removal_of_support_for_tf_prefix).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [higorbarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23997/higorbarb/) on 2015-09-26**:
Thanks Moore, I removed the forward slashes in the `frame_id` of messages and it worked.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-12-05**:
@Tom Moore  Do you mean that robot_localization can not be used with other SLAM packages like hector_mapping, karto_slam at the same time? Since these SLAM packages publish map->odom. Thanks!